# Azure Resource Group Deployment Fails

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-rm-template

I have an Azure Resource Group Deployment project in Visual Studio 2019 that validates and deploys fine from Visual Studio, however when I try to deploy it through Azure Release Pipeline with an Azure Resource Group Deployment Task it **intermittently** fails with the error:

> The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized:
>   'Required property 'type' not found in JSON. Path
>   'properties.template.resources[6]', line 1, position 3759.'. Task
>   failed while creating or updating the template deployment.

I haven't been able to find any helpful information in my research of the problem.
Here is the template:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "sql_name": {
      "defaultValue": "project-sql",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "name": {
      "defaultValue": "a-data-factory",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "location": {
      "defaultValue": "Central US",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "apiVersion": {
      "defaultValue": "2018-06-01",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "gitAccountName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "gitRepositoryName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "gitBranchName": {
      "defaultValue": "foo-branch",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "gitRootFolder": {
      "defaultValue": "/",
      "type": "String"
    },
    "gitProjectName": {
      "type": "String"
    },
    "ssisdbname": {
      "type": "String",
      "defaultValue": "SSISDB"
    },
    "factoryName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": "Data Factory Name",
      "defaultValue": "a-data-factory"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "factoryId": "[concat('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', parameters('factoryName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('sql_name')]",
      "location": "northcentralus",
      "kind": "v12.0",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "theadmin",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "",
        "version": "12.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sql_name'), '/dummyDB')]",
      "location": "northcentralus",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sql_name'))]"
      ],
      "sku": {
        "name": "S0",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "v12.0,user",
      "properties": {
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "maxSizeBytes": 268435456000,
        "catalogCollation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "zoneRedundant": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
      "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sql_name'), '/dummerDB')]",
      "location": "northcentralus",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sql_name'))]"
      ],
      "sku": {
        "name": "S0",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "kind": "v12.0,user",
      "properties": {
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "maxSizeBytes": 268435456000,
        "catalogCollation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "zoneRedundant": false
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/encryptionProtector",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sql_name'), '/current')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sql_name'))]"
      ],
      "kind": "servicemanaged",
      "properties": {
        "serverKeyName": "ServiceManaged",
        "serverKeyType": "ServiceManaged"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules",
      "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('sql_name'), '/AllowAllWindowsAzureIps')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sql_name'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories",
      "apiVersion": "[parameters('apiVersion')]",
      "name": "[parameters('factoryName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/theIntegrationRuntime1')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/integrationRuntimes",
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
          "properties": {
            "type": "Managed",
            "typeProperties": {
              "computeProperties": {
                "location": "Central US",
                "nodeSize": "Standard_D2_v3",
                "numberOfNodes": 1,
                "maxParallelExecutionsPerNode": 2
              },
              "ssisProperties": {
                "catalogInfo": {
                  "catalogServerEndpoint": "project-sql.database.windows.net",
                  "catalogAdminUserName": "theadmin",
                  "catalogAdminPassword": {
                    "type": "SecureString",
                    "value": ""
                  },
                  "catalogPricingTier": "S0"
                },
                "edition": "Standard",
                "licenseType": "LicenseIncluded"
              }
            }
          },
          "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.DataFactory/factories', parameters('factoryname'))]" ]
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "repoConfiguration": {
          "type": "FactoryVSTSConfiguration",
          "accountName": "[parameters('gitAccountName')]",
          "repositoryName": "[parameters('gitRepositoryName')]",
          "collaborationBranch": "[parameters('gitBranchName')]",
          "rootFolder": "[parameters('gitRootFolder')]",
          "projectName": "[parameters('gitProjectName')]"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sql_name'))]" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: this looks fine, show how you are deploying this in ADO?

Comment: just using a simple Azure Release Pipeline with an Azure Resource Group Deployment Task...it usually succeeds, intermittently fails.

Comment: hosted agent? how are you delivering templates to the agent? try updating the task to the latest version?

Comment: I have a self hosted agent.

Comment: I'd never get why people are only answering some of the questions asked. try using powershell task instead of resource group deployment task. i, personally, never use deployment task because its lacking functionallity

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, it turns out that the release pipeline was pointing to an old build artifact that had a malformed template.

Comment: what do you mean "trying to help". that was the question I've asked specifically. `how are you delivering templates to the agent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Release Pipeline was pointed to an old build artifact with a malformed template.